# In extjs4 how to catch multiple checked tree nodes

Tags: checkbox, extjs4, treeview, nodes

i am working in extjs4. I have created treepanel view as-
[image]

i want to catch id's of selected tree nodes on click of submit button. So how to catch these multiple selected tree nodes in  controller of extjs4 on click of submit button?

Comment: i got some reference from link "http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/example/build/KitchenSink/ext-theme-neptune/#tree-two". So there is onCheckedNodesClick function for retrieving checked nodes. But how to call this method in controller? Please can someone help me

Answer (score 0):

If you need to get all checked nodes use [getChecked()](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.tree.Panel-method-getChecked).
Here's example [get checked nodes.](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/examples/tree/check-tree.html)

Comment: sir..i followed way you have suggested. But its giving me error as "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'on_Select' ".

Comment: this.on_Select it's your own function in controller. I update my answer.

Comment: Thanx sir for helping me..But in on_Select function how to get multiple checked tree nodes?